# get value mysql count and save to table

Tags: php, mysql

What i have here is to get the value of my count and save to my table but it's not working. I just want to get the count value, can you help me ? i will appreciate any answer. No problem with displaying with count but only in saving in my table.

```
    <form method="POST">
        Date : <input type="text" value="<?=$p_date?>" name="datereceived" />
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="save">
    </form>
```

**PHP**

```
    <?        
        $sql="SELECT allinvty3.*, barcode.* ,  sample.*, count(barcode.itemcode) as icount  
    from barcode INNER JOIN sample on barcode.itemcode = sample.in_code INNER JOIN allinvty3 on 
    barcode.itemcode = allinvty3.in_code WHERE barcode.refnumber = '$temp'
 GROUP BY barcode.itemcode";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $icount = $row['icount'];
        }

        if(isset($_POST['save'])){
            $sql = "UPDATE barcode SET datereceived ='$p_date', actualacount = '".$icount."', status='COMPLETE' WHERE status='PENDING'";   
            $conn->query($sql) ;     
        } 
    ?>
```

Comment: check if your $_post['save'] is set or not. try echo inside if or echo the $_post['save variable'].

Comment: define not working. Also frmat your code. Also note that you reall;y don;t want to bring javascript into the picture .Just test your mysql query with php in isolation in the browser.

Comment: You don't need to escape the sql in the second query... You just need to do `actualacount = '$icount'`

Answer (score 3):

Because you have an error in your SQL. Try this

```
$sql = "UPDATE barcode SET
        datereceived ='".$p_date."' , actualacount ='".$icount."' ,
        status='COMPLETE'  WHERE status='PENDING'";
```

Comment: not working, everything works fine expect for my Mysql count. Couldn't get the value to update data in table.

Comment: You should check the value of $p_date and $icount before your SQL update. What it returns? You can use var_dump($variable) to check this.

Comment: boolean false, what if i'm updating two or more items?